# Adding a custom INSERT query when adding a comment/post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am going to be starting a project where a client has 2 sites - 1 built in Wordpress and 1 using a proprietary CMS. The client has a post category that exists on their proprietary site and they want to be able to post in this category and it to be added to a category on on the Wordpress site and vice versa. As far as I can see, this would be a fairy complex - especially as the comments would need to be synchronised as well.

Has anyone had experience doing anything like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of the databases can reach the other, you could make use of Views.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this very well using [triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) (if available) to replicate the data.
I can't provide a more concrete tip, but I figure you'll find all the informationn you need, now that you know what to search for.

How *complex* it will be is rather dependent on how different Wordpress and the proprietary CMS are.